# How can I test areStatesEqual in a redux connected component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a redux connected component that is utilising `areStatesEqual` in the [`options`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)) argument in the `redux connect` api to avoid re-rendering.

*`shouldComponentUpdate` does the same job, but a lot slower in my use case.*

I'm struggling to test multiple state updates, asserting that under certain conditions this component believes the states are equal, and shouldn't re-render.

I'm using [`react-mock-store`](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store) for other components, but that only deals with static state, not dynamic. Also using mocha & enzyme elsewhere too.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can test this behaviour?

(*This is a simplified version of a more complicated component*)

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'redux';

import MyComponent from './my-component';

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  text: state.a.text[props.id],
});

const areStatesEqual = (next, prev) => {
  return next.a === prev.a;
};

const options = { areStatesEqual };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, undefined, undefined, options)(MyComponent);
```

MyComponent is a simple functional component that just accepts props and renders:

```
export default function Label({ text }) {
  return <p>{text}</p>;
}
```

Comment: Jest may help you https://facebook.github.io/jest/

Comment: @Héctor do you have any further information other than just pointing me to the docs homepage?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to test the logic by exporting the `areStatesEqual` function and doing a simple test.

```
export const areStatesEqual = (next, prev) => {
  return next.a === prev.a;
};
```

I haven't figured out a way to test the flow of the lifecycle of a component